# VirtualBox won't forward port 80

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Windows 8.1x64 host, Debian 8.3 guest. I've got 2 network adapters set up: 1st is NAT and 2nd is Host-only. I have set up port forwarding for ports 22 and 80 for NAT adapter. Port 22 works (meaning I can SSH using my public IP), port 80 doesn't, connection times out. However, if I use a browser to connect to the IP from the Host-only adapter, everything work fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Below you can see the screenshots of configuration of the NAT adaptor, netstat output from host and router configuration.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why was this moved here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As dumb as it may sound, the issue was that the router had port 80 reserved for remote management (despite being disabled). There was no indication that this was the case. I found this out when doing the same setup on another router of the same vendor (TP-Link) - this one has flagged that port 80 is reserved. Changing remote management port on the router to 81 fixed the issue.